# TriangulateMesh failed at this kind mesh

Tags: mesh

[image]

```
mesh = ImageMesh@ImageResize[imgB, 512]
```

`TriangulateMesh` or `DiscreteRegion` failed at mesh,just quit kernel.

What's the problem.

Are there any options or methods to avoid this and triangulate the mesh?

Comment: I am afraid, we can do nothing about this. Please inform Wolfram Technical Support.

Comment: Why we need `512`? `300` is ok here.

Comment: @cvgmt 512 is not necessary, but it restricts the ability of Triangulate.